# When using black stroke color to animate a imported model, the stroke color turns grey after animating it

Tags: animation, 2d

[image: The stroke when it's over an imported image]

The stroke shown over the imported asset

Comment: I think it's just using the 3D interface on 2d animation to fix this problem since I did that but im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it by going to 3d view in the 2d animation interface and then moved the imported image to be *behind* the stroke so the stroke is not interfering with the image plane